# Equivalent to Java summaryStatistics in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I am porting some Java code to Scala and need to extract some really basic statistical values, which include the **count**, **maximum**, **minimum** and **average** from a stream of long values.

In Java I have solved this problem with this method:

```
public static Stats calcStats(Iterable<Ad> iterable) {
    LongSummaryStatistics longSummaryStatistics = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).mapToLong(Ad::getEvent_time).summaryStatistics();
    return new Stats(longSummaryStatistics.getMin(), longSummaryStatistics.getMax(), round(longSummaryStatistics.getAverage()),
            longSummaryStatistics.getCount());
}
```

Is there a similar method to extract these values in one go in the Scala libraries (without using extra libraries like Spark)?

Right now I am using some code similar to this one:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val l = List(("s1", 1L), ("s2", 2L), ("s3", 3L), ("s4", 4L))
  val stats = summaryStatistics(l.iterator)
  println("min: %d, max: %d, avg: %f".format(stats._1, stats._2, stats._3))
}

def summaryStatistics(iter: Iterator[(String, Long)]): (Long, Long, Double) = {
  val stats = iter.map((tuple: (String, Long)) => tuple._2)
    .foldLeft((Long.MaxValue, Long.MinValue, 0L, 0L))((a, t) => (Math.min(t, a._1), Math.max(t, a._2), a._3 + 1, a._4 + t))
  (stats._1, stats._2, stats._4 / (stats._3 * 1.0))
}
```

This prints out:

```
min: 1, max: 4, avg: 2.500000
```

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain?

Comment: At least give me a hint of what I can improve ...

Comment: The java class are available in Scala, so there's no need for something equivalent, you can use them :)

Comment: @C4stor but how would you use it in Scala? Can you use it with `scala.collection.Iterator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to C4stor, you can use more Scala collections like this:

```
import java.util.LongSummaryStatistics

def main(): Unit = {
  val l = List(("s1", 1L), ("s2", 2L), ("s3", 3L), ("s4", 4L))
  // .view here is a trick to make it semantically more similar to Java Streams i.e. to avoid materializaiton of the mapped list
  val stats = summaryStatistics(l.view.map(_._2))
  println("min: %d, max: %d, avg: %f".format(stats.getMin, stats.getMax, stats.getAverage))
}


def summaryStatistics(col: TraversableOnce[Long]): LongSummaryStatistics = {
  col.foldLeft(new LongSummaryStatistics)((stat, el) => {
    stat.accept(el)
    stat
  })
}
```

Or if you want to use a potential of parallel support that is implemented in `LongSummaryStatistics`, you may use `aggregate` instead of `foldLeft` such as:

```
def summaryStatistics(col: TraversableOnce[Long]): LongSummaryStatistics = {
  col.aggregate(new LongSummaryStatistics)((stat, el) => {
    stat.accept(el)
    stat
  }, (s1, s2) => {
    s1.combine(s2)
    s1
  })
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's nice too :) in a "let's lift explicitly the java lib" style. I like both the call to .view and the use of TraversableOnce[Long] which are imo very scalaesque things :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the java lib directly, by going through the java world just a bit :)

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val l = List(("s1", 1L), ("s2", 2L), ("s3", 3L), ("s4", 4L))
    val stats = StreamSupport.stream(l.asJava.spliterator(), false).mapToLong(x => x._2).summaryStatistics()
    println("min: %d, max: %d, avg: %f".format(stats.getMin, stats.getMax, stats.getAverage))
}
```

Note the import of the JavaConverters, and the little "asJava" added in the code to match the StreamSupport API :)

Comment: I like your solution really and had a hard time deciding which solution to accept. I ended up accepting SergGr's solution, because of the parallel support. Anyway many thanks for this.

Comment: Don't sweat it, as long as you can move forward, everything's good :) You're welcome